# Can I make a batch script run a 32 or 64 bit program accordingly?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, batch-file, 32-bit

I want to make a batch or command script that can find the proper program to use in accordance with the local machines processor architecture for 32-bit and 64-bit programs.

One program I would like to try this with is [WinRAR](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm). I want to place the 64-bit version in a folder called "x64" and the 32-bit in a folder labeled "x86" with the script besides these folders.

I have noticed that some programs such as [Cheat Engine](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.cheatengine.org/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwj23oXJxOnUAhXr7oMKHRXxA6IQFggLMAA&usg=AFQjCNFNQeH7A3e-vVPY9yRoUTASm_CgoQ), have a 32 and 64 bit version that *also* include an executable that can do this.

Currently my only lead is the `%process_architecture%` variable. This was the script I made using [@dbenham's](https://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham) original script:

```
echo %processor_architecture%%processor_architew6432% | findstr 64 >nul && set "prog=x64\WinRAR x64.exe" || set "prog=x86\WinRAR x86.exe"
```

Comment: You will faster get answer for this question on stackoverflow.

Comment: @kelin Not so. It would get closed as too broad on [SO] as the OP has provided no VB code. In any case it can be done in batch. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I find the proper program to use as per the processor architecture?

> This was the script I used:
>
> ```
> echo %processor_architecture%%processor_architew6432% | findstr 64 >nul && set "prog=x64\WinRAR x64.exe" || set "prog=x86\WinRAR x86.exe"
> ```

Notes:

- The above code used by the OP was taken from [this comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1228162/can-i-make-a-batch-script-run-an-x86-or-x64-bit-program-accordingly/1228167?noredirect=1#comment1796970_1228167) by [dbenham](https://superuser.com/users/109090/dbenham).
- `%processor_architew6432%` is normally undefined on a 64 bit system (the exception is when a 32-bit process is created by a 64-bit process). See [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274.aspx) for more information.

I normally use `wmic OS get OSArchitecture` to get the OS bitness.

The following batch file should get you started:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq skip=1 tokens=*" %%i in (`wmic OS get OSArchitecture ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  set "_bits=%%i"
  rem remove spaces
  set "_bits=!_bits: =!"
  )
if "%_bits%" EQU "64bits" (
  rem 64bit OS
  set "prog=x64\WinRAR x64.exe"
  ) else (
  rem 32bit OS
  set "prog=x86\WinRAR x86.exe"
  )
rem do something with %prog%
call %prog%
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [WOW64 Implementation Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384274.aspx)
- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.

Comment: I gave your script a shot, but it does the same thing no matter what variables I use.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli What are you doing with `%prog%` once it has been set?

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli what is "the same thing" that it does? You've not said what doesn't actually work in the script you use.

Comment: I changed each one accordingly to `%processor_architew6432%` and `%processor_architecture%`. I apologize, I am still figuring out how batch scripting works.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli Setting a variable (like `prog`) doesn't actually *do* anything. Try adding `call %prog%` once it has been set. Answer updated.

Comment: @Mr.Mendelli what ***exactly*** are you changing to %processor_architew6432% and %processor_architecture%? Post your script.

Comment: I was changing the `prog=` variables before the target paths, but [@DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) provided the solution, my script is working now.

Comment: @dbenham Hmm. I've added one to my answer. It should really have been in the question though ...

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't read the end of the question carefully. I didn't realize he already put the link in the question.

Comment: @dbenham NP. The one in the question just links to your user id. I've added a link to the exact comment in the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my way of finding out:

`if exist %windir%\syswow64 ( set ARCH=x64 ) else ( set ARCH=x86 )`

Simple. Works every time